# My www version of site is redirecting to the non www version of another site on the same nginx server

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have two domains setup on one server running LEMP.

When i access the domain2.co.uk everything is fine. But when I go to www.domain2.co.uk it is redirecting to www.domain1.co.uk

nginx.conf

```
    user www-data www-data;
    worker_processes  4;
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }
    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        sendfile        on;
        tcp_nopush      on;
        tcp_nodelay     off;
        keepalive_timeout  5;
        gzip  on;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        include /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

## ../sites-enabled/domain1.co.uk

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  www.domain1.co.uk;
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain1.co.uk/$1 permanent;
       }
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name domain1.co.uk;
            access_log /home/me/public_html/domain1.co.uk/log/access.log;
            error_log /home/me/public_html/domain1.co.uk/log/error.log;
            location /  {
                        root   /home/me/public_html/domain1.co.uk/public/;
                        index  index.php index.html;
                        # WordPress supercache &  permalinks.
                        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/wordpress_params.super_cache;
                        }
            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            location ~ \.php$
                    {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/me/public_html/domain1.co.uk/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
                        }
       }
```

## ../sites-enabled/domain2.co.uk

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  www.domain2.co.uk;
        rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain2.co.uk/$1 permanent;
}
server {

            listen 80;
            server_name domain2.co.uk;

            access_log /home/me/public_html/domain2.co.uk/log/access.log;
            error_log /home/me/public_html/domain2.co.uk/log/error.log;

            location /
            {

                root   /home/me/public_html/domain2.co.uk/public/;
                index  index.php index.html;

                # Basic version of WordPress parameters, supporting nice permalinks.
                # include /usr/local/nginx/conf/wordpress_params.regular;
                # Advanced version of WordPress parameters supporting nice permalinks and WP Super Cache plugin
                include /usr/local/nginx/conf/wordpress_params.super_cache;
            }

            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            #
            location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/me/public_html/domain2/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
      }
```

Comment: You've probably have some error in www.domain2.co.uk domain: missed ';', non-printable character, etc. Try re-writing it from scratch in a new file.

Comment: Any chance that the script has a redirect coded into it as well as nginx?

Comment: @rvs I tried what you suggested and it never resolved the issue.

Comment: @Jack M not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: You are passing control from nginx to wordpress or some other .php file.  Are those scripts doing a redirect?

Comment: Make sure you're testing the redirect with curl -I and not a browser.  A browser may have cached an incorrect 301 if you had a problem in the past, and sometimes they'll continue to use that cached 301 long after the server configuration has been corrected.

Comment: @Jack Wodpress is a fresh bare minimal install. It was installed and configured on domain2.co.uk and works fine. It's just when I checked that the www version would correctly 301 to domain1.co.uk I come across the issue.

Comment: @kolbyjack - thank you that done the trick. Curl confirmed it was redirecting correctly, so I cleared the cache and bingo! If you want to add it as answer I will mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're testing the redirect with curl -I and not a browser. A browser may have cached an incorrect 301 if you had a problem in the past, and sometimes they'll continue to use that cached 301 long after the server configuration has been corrected.